# Use SBT offline with file based repository

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I need to use sbt in an offline environment, but I can stage all of the necessary jars on the filesystem as a local repository.  How do I define ~/.sbt/repositories so that it will check the local filesystem for the jars that sbt (and my project) needs?  For bonus points, what's the easiest way to set up the local file based repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all explained at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html

In a nutshell you have to put this into ~/.sbt/repositories

```
[repositories]
  local
  sharedRepo: file:///path/to/my/shared/repo/.m2/repository
```

and invoke sbt (or play/activator) with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`

This will make sure that only local and shared repository is used for resolving dependencies.

The easiest way to make sure that local repository contains the jars you need is to delete the ~/.sbt/repositories file and do an `sbt update` on the project while online (without the -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true parameter). After that restore the ~/.sbt/repositories file and all resolving will be done from your local repository only.

For setting up a private repository look at artifactory, it has an open source version that is enough for a maven repository.

http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: I don't just want to use the local .ivy2 cache -- I want to check the filesystem for repositories.  For example, the filesystem could have the repositories mount via nfs -- but the local ivy2 cache is where local installations live, so can't be shared across users.

Comment: If by checking the filesystem you mean actively searching for repositories I don't think it is possible. The exact repository url/file location must be specified in the file. I updated the answer to show how to specify the custom repository in the ~/.sbt/repositories file.